# Invalid ObjectName xxx.dbo.xxx, but it is there

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, savechanges

I do not understand, why the following Code does not work:

```
        //Database connection
        using (var db = new KassenautomatEntities())
        {
            //Create Model
            var quittung = new WAWI_Quittungen
            {
                QuittungText = "WebInterface",
                QuittungBetrag = amount,
                QuittungDatum = DateTime.Now,
                KartenIDKassierer = 0,
                KartenIDKunde = userInfo.CardId,
                Zahlungsart = 4,
                ClientNr = WebInterfaceInfo.ClientId,
                LastPrintDate = null,
                PrintedCount = 0,
                StornoQuittungID = null,
                Status = 0
            };

            //Save Model
            db.WAWI_Quittungen.Add(quittung);
            db.SaveChanges(); //<----- Crash
```

I get this error:

> Invalid Objectname 'KasseJournal.dbo.WAWI_Quittungen'

[image]

General every table works for me. This is the only one, which does not.

`WAWI_Quittungen` has a Primary Key with autoincrement called `QuittungID`, which I have not defined here, but I don't think, that is the problem.

I also deleted the table from the diagramm and added it from the database.

Something point of interest:

- In SQL Studio it is named `[Kassenautomat].[dbo].[WAWI_Quittungen]` instead of `KasseJournal.dbo.WAWI_Quittungen`.
- If I read from this table via entity framework, I have no problem.
- I have done a Text Search in the entire Solution for `KasseJournal` but zero results.

Of course I have googled a lot. I have not one of this problems:

- Database Trigger
- Wrong Database connected
- Pluralize New Object set to false

What I am missing?

---

Connectionstring:

```
 <add name="KassenautomatEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Database.KassenautomatModel.csdl|res://*/Models.Database.KassenautomatModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.Database.KassenautomatModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=Kassenautomat;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

---

Working Generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
        FROM [dbo].[WAWI_Quittungen] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE [Extent1].[KartenIDKunde] = @p__linq__0
    )  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Not working SQL:

```
INSERT [dbo].[WAWI_Quittungen]([QuittungText], [QuittungBetrag], [...])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, NULL, @7, NULL, @8)
SELECT [QuittungID]
FROM [dbo].[WAWI_Quittungen]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [QuittungID] = scope_identity()
```

---

Stacktrace:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Ungültiger Objektname 'KasseJournal.dbo.WAWI_Quittungen'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +1787814
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5341674
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +61
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +90
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +377
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds) +1421
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +177
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +137
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +402
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +166
   System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +10
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +234
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +159

[UpdateException: Fehler beim Aktualisieren der Einträge. Weitere Informationen finden Sie in der internen Ausnahme.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +334
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.<Update>b__2(UpdateTranslator ut) +9
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update(T noChangesResult, Func`2 updateFunction) +132
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityAdapter.Update() +105
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<SaveChangesToStore>b__35() +11
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +288
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction) +157
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<SaveChangesInternal>b__27() +21
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +162
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesInternal(SaveOptions options, Boolean executeInExistingTransaction) +221
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +6
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +113

[DbUpdateException: Fehler beim Aktualisieren der Einträge. Weitere Informationen finden Sie in der internen Ausnahme.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +196
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +26
   System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20
   WebInterface.Controllers.RechargeCardController.HandleSuccessPayment(Decimal amount, UserInfo userInfo) in d:\Daten\Dev\Conwell\WebInterface\Controllers\RechargeCardController.cs:336
   WebInterface.Controllers.RechargeCardController.PaymentExecute(PaymentInitViewModel model) in d:\Daten\Dev\Conwell\WebInterface\Controllers\RechargeCardController.cs:222
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.ActionInvocation.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod() +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +117
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +323
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +136
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +133
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +70
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +139
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +59
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651796
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Do the other tables that work use the same DbContext? When you trace the SQL generated by EF from your "working" tables, does it show "KasseJournal" or "Kassenautomat"?  Can you show us your connection string?

Comment: I am relative new to EF. How can I trace the generated SQL? Will post the connection string in a minute.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464#Log

Comment: Thanks @sstan I have updated my question. It shows only dbo.table

Comment: Very odd. Have you tried running the generated insert statement manually in SQL Management Studio? Based on the info you have provided so far, it does appear to be database specific, and may not be related to EF at all.  But doing this test will confirm it.

Comment: Is this Code First, or EDMX ?

Comment: This is Database first @SamAxe

Comment: You could try opening your EDMX file (its XML) in a text editor and seeing if the rogue Database name (KasseJournal) is in there.

Comment: Thank you @SamAxe for your suggestion, but the string is not there.

Comment: Thank you for your help @sstan I have tried to execute it. From Master it does not work, but it work if I change the Context to `Kassenautomat`. I realy do not understand why EF want to run again `KasseJournal`. I do not find this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. I give you wrong Information, sorry about that.

It was a Trigger.

I was looking into Database Triggers instead of Table Triggers. I did not know that MsSQL has a Trigger Definition for every single Table. In MySQL it is one big Trigger Table.

So I removed the Trigger and everything works fine.